# Matlab - plot two pcolors on top of each other, with different colormaps

Tags: matlab, colors, plot

I'm plotting two pcolors on top of each other (using the m_map algorithm m_pcolor).  The reason for this is that the second pcolor has transparency in it, and so shows the pcolor underneath.  The first plot consists of just ones and zeroes, and I would like it to be just black and white.  I would like the second to use the colormap jet, but I can't work out how to set one colormap without changing the other.  My code at the moment is:

```
h1 = m_pcolor(Lon', Lat', black_background);
hold on; 
h = m_pcolor(Lon', Lat', input_matrix);
```

Thanks in advance,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this limited application, the easiest way is probably to append a row of zeros onto the colormap, deal with scaling (the `clim` property) yourself so that each plot takes advantage of the appropriate part of the colormap.

```
cm=colormap('jet'); %# Nx3
cm = [cm; 0 0 0]; %# append black row: (N+1)x3

h1 = m_pcolor(Lon',Lat',black_background);
set(h1,'clim',[length(colormap),length(colormap)])

hold on
h2 = m_pcolor(Lon', Lat', input_matrix);
set(h2,'clim',[length(colormap)-1, length(colormap)-1])
```

This should get you close, but I haven't tested it since I'm not on my matlab machine.

Another option is [freezeColors](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7943) from the file exchange (but this may only work for different axes within the same figure window, I'm not sure about different plots in the same axes object).

Comment: freezeColors does the trick brilliantly (and your handwritten solution looks great too)!  thanks a lot for ***two*** great answers!